# Problems building python interpreter with custom module

Tags: c++, python, linux, gnu-make, python-2.6

I am trying to build the python-2.6 interpreter on Linux with a custom module embeded into the interpreter. I tried following the instructions on 'Extending Python with C or C++' from the Python documentation but something keeps on going wrong. I keep getting the following error when building :

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Modules/_custommodule.c', needed by `Modules/_custommodule.o'.  Stop.
```

I've checked the generated Makefile and it does contain references to my _custommodule.c file and has the proper libraries linked for dependencies but is not being made for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's usually because you don't have a file called custommodule.c available to make. Check that:

- that file exists.
- you're in the right directory when you make.

If that doesn't work, Edit your post with a directory listing of that directory.